# How can I determine the safe width of the PCB traces so that they withstand the momentary short circuit current before the circuit breaker trips?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, electricity

[image]

Many lamps are supplied by 220v and a circuit breaker through a PCB as in the picture. The total current of this circuit is 1A. For this implemintation I am going to use 2A circuit breaker. I am afraid that a short circuit could happen at the load and the traces of the PCB may explode. How can I determine the safe width of the PCB traces so that they withstand the momentary short circuit current before the circuit breaker trips? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Use one of the many online ampacity calculators?

Comment: Another possible approach to this is [inrush current limiting (ICL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current_limiter).

Comment: @PlasmaHH Actually I could do that but I dont know how much the short circuit current would be. It could be 10A or 30A. It could be more or less.

Comment: @Majid_L A short circuit more likely would be 6 kA (kilo amperes) more or less.

Comment: @Majid_L: How should we determine safe sizes if we don't get a specification of what it has to handle for how long?

Comment: @Marko Buršič this is going to be true if there were not a circuit breaker. As a prove, connect a 220v 15w lamp through a suitable circuit breaker using 21 AWG cable and then make a short circuit. The breaker will trip without damaging the cable even though the fusing current of 21 AWG cable is 700A at 32ms.

Comment: @Majid_L The circuit breaker itself disconnects the section, but it doesn't limit the current. At SC it  will disconnect for example in  5ms. The I^2*t value is now 6kA^2*5ms=180,000A^2*s. Whenever it will melt or not, you should calculate with some calculation: http://www.ultracad.com/articles/fusingr.pdf

Comment: @PlasmaHH Do you know any trace current calculators for fault currents rather than steady currents?

Comment: @NickAlexeev How would inrush current limiting help? It would postpone the breaker tripping, so the short would be limited initially but it would last longer. It's entirely possible that would _increase_ the dissipated energy.

Answer (score 1):

A [fuse](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/bel-fuse-inc/0679H1000-01/507-2026-6-ND/6139835) might be more suitable.
[image]

SMD Fuse : Current Rating   1A  , Voltage Rating - 350Vac , $0.18 @ 500pc

or a Polyfuse 1A $0.40 (500pc)  10A max  radial
[image]

---

The whole idea of a fuse or a breaker or a Polyfuse to choose protection that reacts quicker than the fragile path. If a short thin track heats up faster than a breaker or a polyfuse, then the only choice is a fast blow SMT fuse. got it?  Which was my 1st answer.  Ensure the track resistance is much much less than the SMT resistance, by design of the tracks and additional solder if necessary or busbar. A 2A fuse is 41 mOhm cold.

Otherwise if you don't then the track becomes the fuse.  Beware of high resistance The whole idea of a fuse or a breaker or a Polyfuse to choose protection that reacts quicker than the fragile path. If a short thin track heats up faster than a breaker or a polyfuse, then the only choice is a fast blow SMT fuse. got it?  Which was my 1st answer.  Ensure the track resistance is much much less than the SMT resistance, by design of the tracks and additional solder if necessary or busbar. A 2A fuse is 41 mOhm cold. **Otherwise if you don't then the track becomes the fuse. 
 Beware of high resistance contacts.**

Comment: While it seems a good solution but I think it is not practical. Because if a lamp burned out a huge amount of current would go through the fuse and blow it. For sure in my approach the circuit breaker is going to trip too but it is easier to turn the circuit breaker back on instead of changing the fuse.

Comment: Polyfuse could be a possible solution though. Can it handle 220v dead short current?

Comment: An NTC (ICL) will protect a short cct on cold start but not hot and the Polyfuse is only rated for 10A so looks like a fuse is safest

Comment: @Majid_L Wait... Are you concerned about a lamp burning out or a dead short? Those are two very different things.

Comment: @marcelm My main concern is the dead short.

Answer (score 0):

A cube of copper 35 microns on a side (35 microns is the standard thickness of CU foil at 1ounce/foot^2) has 0.0005 (500 microOhms) resistance. I'll use a specific heat I know well ---- that of silicon, 2 picoJoules/cubic micron/deg C ---- to run through the math. In that 35micron cube, there are ~~ 40,000 cubes of size 1micron. Thus the energy storage is 40,000 * 2pJ/micron^2/deg C or 80 nanoJoules/35microncube CU. (again, I'm using silicon, not CU value).

What is the energy generated in that 35 micron cube, at 1 amp? P = I^2*R, or 1*1*0.0005, or 500 microJoules/second.

Lets just divide 500 microJoules/second by 80 nanoJoules/deg C, and we find the dimensions are "degC/second" and the scale factor 500,000nJ/80nJ = 6,000.

Thus the rate of heating is 6,000 degree C/second.

Now you need to compute the specific heat of a cubic micron of copper, and tweak that 6,000 to a more accurate number.

---

edit If you want 60 degree C rise, over 1 second, you need 100X the width I used. That 35micron cube is 1.4 mils, or 0.0014 inches. Thus 0.14 inches seems safe.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have made your calculations for 1 amp current which is the steady state of the circuit. The problem is that I can not find a way to estimate the circuit's short current which I believe, with a type B circuit breaker, could last for 40ms.

Comment: Thus a 40 millisecond short, at 25 amps, would also produce 60 degree Centigrade temperature rise. And 250 amps would produce 600 degree Centigrade rise; how fast will the breaker trip, at 250 Amps?

Comment: The breaker trips at currents higher than 10 Amps after about 40ms.

Comment: What is the wiring resistance?

Comment: It is about 40 meters of 21 AWG cable. This cable has a resistance of 42 mΩ/m thus total resistance is going to be about 1.68Ω

Answer (score 0):

you could use a calculator like:http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit/  . Go to the "Fusing Current" Tab. Here you could insert the width of your track and how much time do you want the track to hold the short circuit current. The short circuit current that the given track width can Sustain for the given time is calculated by the program. you have to be sure that your fuse, CB can disconnect the current in Shorter than the inserted time in the program.

For example, say you have a track width of 3.1 mm and you want that this track holds a short cicuit current for 1ms. The program will tell you that the maximum short circuit current that this track can Sustain in 1ms is About 1kA. Based on this result you have to make sure that your CB/Fuse can disconnect a short circuit current of 1kA in less than 1ms (based on its datasheet). so Long your track width is known, you can then Play with the time and get the maxumum allowable short circuit current at each time, then see if your ciruit breaker can handle These short circuit currents in less time than you insert in the calculator.

Answer (score -1):

I would not worry about that small amount of time. The goal is to have a trace/wire that has enough ampacity for the standard/max normal current load. In a short circuit situation with a circuit breaker, yes you would get a TON of amps, almost nothing would be able to handle that, however you only get them for a VERY short amount of time.

When you take time into consideration, your board wont blow up when something shorts, as long as the circuit breaker trips. Nothing will have enough time to heat up to a point if the current is cut off almost immediately.